# SwiftUI publishing an environment change from within view update

Tags: swiftui, environment-variables

The app has a `model` that stores the user's current preference for light/dark mode, which the user can change by clicking on a button:

```
class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var mode: ColorScheme = .light
```

The ContentView's `body` tracks the model, and adjusts the colorScheme when the model changes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var dataModel = DataModel()

var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) { ...
        }
        .environmentObject(dataModel)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, dataModel.mode)
```

As of Xcode Version 14.0 beta 5, this is producing a purple warning: `Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.` Is there another way to do this? Or is it a hiccup in the beta release? Thanks!

Comment: Not reproducible here, so it seems depends on your other code. Needed MRE.

Comment: @Asperi This post on the Apple dev forum has an MRE. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899

Comment: Not reproduced for me. Xcode 14b5 / iOS 16 / Simulator on MacBookPro M1Pro.

Comment: `...which the user can change by clicking on a button:...`, show us the code of the Button and how you `change` the `dataModel`. You can usually resolve this type of issue, using `DispatchQueue.main.async {....}`

Comment: May be setting as environment a value which is also in another environment may be forbidden as incoherency may occur. But they is just a guess

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the issue is since the author didn't post complete code. But for the issue in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899, I just added my analysis and solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899?page=1#724014022). Hope it helps.

Comment: I see this error when using MapKit's MapAnnotation. if I replace that with MapMarker,  the warning disappears.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Update: 2022-09-28

Xcode 14.1 Beta 3 (finally) fixed the "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior"

See: https://www.donnywals.com/xcode-14-publishing-changes-from-within-view-updates-is-not-allowed-this-will-cause-undefined-behavior/

---

Full disclosure - I'm not entirely sure *why* this is happening but these have been the two solutions I have found that seem to work.

[image: The error message]

[image: Error in action]

## Example Code

```swift
// -- main view
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ViewOne()
       .environmentObject(vm)
    }
  }
}

// -- initial view
struct ViewOne: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      vm.isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Open sheet")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $vm.isPresented) {
      SheetView()
    }
  }
}

// -- sheet view
struct SheetView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      vm.isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Close sheet")
    }
  }
}

// -- view model
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isPresented: Bool = false
}
```

### Solution 1

***Note:** from my testing and the example below I still get the error to appear. But if I have a more complex/nested app then the error disappears..*

Adding a `.buttonStyle()` to the button that does the initial toggling.

So within the `ContentView` on the `Button() {}` add in a `.buttonStyle(.plain)` and it will remove the purple error:

```swift
struct ViewOne: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      vm.isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Open sheet")
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain) // <-- here
    .sheet(isPresented: $vm.isPresented) {
      SheetView()
    }
  }
}
```

*^ This is probably more of a hack than solution since it'll output a new view from the modifier and that is probably what is causing it to not output the error on larger views.*

### Solution 2

This one is credit to Alex Nagy (aka. [Rebeloper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a7tuhVpoTQ))

As Alex explains:

> .. with SwiftUI 3 and SwiftUI 4 the data handling kind of changed. How SwiftUI handles, more specifically the `@Published` variable ..

So the solution is to have the boolean trigger to be a `@State` variable within the view and not as a `@Published` one inside the ViewModel. But as Alex points out it can make your views messy and if you have a lot of states in it, or not be able to deep link, etc.

[image: @State only - no ViewModel]

However, since this is the way that SwiftUI 4 wants these to operate, we run the code as such:

```swift
// -- main view
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ViewOne()
    }
  }
}

// -- initial view
struct ViewOne: View {
  @State private var isPresented = false
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Open sheet")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
      SheetView(isPresented: $isPresented)
      // SheetView() <-- if using dismiss() in >= iOS 15
    }
  }
}

// -- sheet view
struct SheetView: View {
  // I'm showing a @Binding here for < iOS 15
  // but you can use the dismiss() option if you
  // target higher
  // @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
  @Binding var isPresented: Bool
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      isPresented.toggle()
      // dismiss()
    } label: {
      Text("Close sheet")
    }
  }
}
```

#### Using the `@Published` and the `@State`

Continuing from the video, if you need to still use the `@Published` variable as it might tie into other areas of your app you can do so with a `.onChange` and a `.onReceive` to link the two variables:

```swift
struct ViewOne: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel
  @State private var isPresented = false
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      vm.isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Open sheet")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
      SheetView(isPresented: $isPresented)
    }
    .onReceive(vm.$isPresented) { newValue in
      isPresented = newValue
    }
    .onChange(of: isPresented) { newValue in
      vm.isPresented = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

[image: With the @State and the @Published variables]

However, this can become really messy in your code if you have to trigger it for every `sheet` or `fullScreenCover`.

#### Creating a ViewModifier

So to make it easier for you to implement it you can create a ViewModifier which Alex has shown works too:

```swift
extension View {
  func sync(_ published: Binding<Bool>, with binding: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
    self
      .onChange(of: published.wrappedValue) { newValue in
        binding.wrappedValue = newValue
      }
      .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) { newValue in
        published.wrappedValue = newValue
      }
  }
}
```

[image: View extension]

And in use on the View:

```swift
struct ViewOne: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var vm: ViewModel
  @State private var isPresented = false
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      vm.isPresented.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("Open sheet")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
      SheetView(isPresented: $isPresented)
    }
    .sync($vm.isPresented, with: $isPresented)

//    .onReceive(vm.$isPresented) { newValue in
//      isPresented = newValue
//    }
//    .onChange(of: isPresented) { newValue in
//      vm.isPresented = newValue
//    }
  }
}
```

---

^ Anything denoted with this is my assumptions and not real technical understanding - I am not a technical knowledgeable :/

Comment: The short of it: We no longer can *Bind* a *@Published* variable. Binding is now exclusive to *@State*

Comment: @Rebeloper is that stated anywhere from Apple as the new desired behaviour or are we seeing a possible bug that had crept in to the final Swift4/Xcode 14?  This seems like a significant change in behaviour that isn't mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: @GerryShaw it looks like it is not a bug. Apple is silent on this. Trying out workarounds as we speak. Will keep you updated. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736513/4514671 is one strange but crucial step to add into Lists and Buttons.

Comment: So it was a bug? Does it work in Xcode 14 as before or did they really change the binding behavior on @Published?

Comment: @adri567 I couldn't see anything in the release notes, but running it now in the 14.1.0b3 doesn't output the error

Answer (score 4):

Try running the code that's throwing the purple error asynchronously, for example, by using `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `Task`.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // environment changing code comes here
}

Task {
    // environment changing code comes here
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue in a *non-binding* environment while dismissing a sheet, however I'm using `Task { @MainActor in`

Answer (score 2):

Improved Solution of Rebel Developer
as a generic function.
[Rebeloper solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3a7tuhVpoTQ)
It helped me a lot.

1- Create extension for it:

```
extension View{
func sync<T:Equatable>(_ published:Binding<T>, with binding:Binding<T>)-> some View{
    self
        .onChange(of: published.wrappedValue) { published in
            binding.wrappedValue = published
        }
        .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) { binding in
            published.wrappedValue = binding
        }
}
```

}

2- sync() ViewModel @Published var to local @State var

```
struct ContentView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var viewModel:ViewModel
@State var fullScreenType:FullScreenType?

var body: some View {
    //..
}
.sync($viewModel.fullScreenType, with: $fullScreenType)
```

Comment: That solution is great, but I think that we can make it even better if we add an `onAppear` to set the initial value. Here is the final `sync` modifier:
```
extension View{
func sync<T:Equatable>(_ published:Binding<T>, with binding:Binding<T>)-> some View{
    self
        .onChange(of: published.wrappedValue) { published in
            binding.wrappedValue = published
        }
        .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) { binding in
            published.wrappedValue = binding
        }
        .onAppear {
            binding.wrappedValue = published
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That solution is great, but I think that we can make it even better if we add an `onAppear` to set the initial value. Here is the final `sync` modifier:

```
extension View{
func sync<T:Equatable>(_ published:Binding<T>, with binding:Binding<T>)-> some View{
    self
        .onChange(of: published.wrappedValue) {
            binding.wrappedValue = $0
        }
        .onChange(of: binding.wrappedValue) {
            published.wrappedValue = $0
        }
        .onAppear {
            binding.wrappedValue = published.wrappedValue
        }
}
```